# Can I set size of NSTextView's autocompletion window?

Tags: cocoa, autocomplete, window, size, nstextview

`NSTextView`'s autocompletion window size has maximum limit and words in the window displayed with trails (`...`). How can I set size of the window manually or allow it to be larger? (bigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this isn't possible. You would need to roll your own completion solution like Xcode does.